# How to find class name via text using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".unitHeading").click(function(){
    urls = this.id;
    heading = $(this).data("id");
    rendition.display(urls);
    classname = $('iframe').contents().text(heading).find('class');
    console.log(classname);
    return false;
});
```

I have an `iframe` file where I am going to find the class name with the help of text here text means `heading`. For example `<p class="block_7">Hello World</p>` through `Hello World` I need to fine class i.e `block_7`. How can I do this?

Comment: So basically you are trying to find an element via its content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `:contains` psuedo-selector:

```js
const heading = 'Hello World';
const $iframe = $('<div><p class="block_7">Hello World</p></div>');
const match = $iframe.find(`p:contains('${heading}')`);
if (match.length) {
  console.log(match[0].className);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If any `<p>` elements containing that text are found, they'll be put into the `match` collection, and then you can look at the `className` of the `<p>`.

Comment: Actually I have only `heading`  i.e `Hello world` and all `<div><p class="block_7">Hello World</p></div>` is a part of iframe. So, I need to find class name through only `Hello World` @CertainPerformance

Comment: What do you mean? From the iframe, all you need to do is ``.find(`p:contains('${heading}')`);`` - by concatenating the `Hello World` part with the `:contains` psuedo-selector, you can find the matching element (if there is one). All it's using is the `Hello World` and the iframe

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `Iframe Contents` and validate the `text`

```js
let iframe = jQuery('iframe#frameId');
$(iframe[0].childNodes).each(function() {
     if($(this).text().includes('Hello World')){
       let el = $(this)[0].nodeValue;
       console.log($(el).attr('class'));
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="frameId">
  <p class="block_7">Hello World</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: I am trying @manikantgautam but nothing happen console error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `:contains()`:

```
$('iframe').contents().find(`:contains('${heading}')`)[0].classList;
```

Comment: `$('iframe').contents().find(`:contains('${heading}')`)` what is it returns?

Comment: `n.fn.init [prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: ":contains(Based on Structure)"]
`